# WP Multisite - multilanguage - swich to other language by click, but "same" content

Tags: multisite, multi-language

I want to run a WP-multisite for 4 languages (in development), and did it so, 4 blogs, each one got the same content but in a different language, same structure, same pages, same postings, same images.

No translation plugin, cause we need and want native translations for out contents. If we publish articles, so we have the articles in 4 languages and post it parallel on this 4 blogs.

Is it possible to swich the whole site-content by click? Now we linked to the index of each blog.

Thank you. (Sorry for my "great" english)

Comment: I am having a similar need. Did you come up with something clever? I would be very interested in a solution where the page editor doesn't have to reload the images twice, only a nice interface where he could fill in the different translations.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling over this question when looking up information on multilingual multisite instances: [WPML (WordPress Multilingual Plugin)](https://wpml.org/) supports what OP was looking for by "linking" posts and pages in the backend across all languages.

If a post/page is linked to all other language variations, you are able to switch between the different languages of the post/page via a widget or something alike.

I have used this in multilingual multisite instances and found it to be the easiest way, especially if you have non-technical people generating content for your sites.